# Why is the sentence structured this way?

Tags: meaning, verbs

> The powers not delegated to the United States by the Constitution, nor prohibited by it to the States, are reserved to the States respectively, or to the people.

I need a little clarification on grammar of this sentence. Is "to" in "prohibited by it to the States" used as a preposition referring to the object here? If yes, why? Why is it incorrect to say "I prohibit it to the  organization or it was prohibited by me to the organization" but it's correct to use the structure as is in the 10th Amendment?

Comment: >Is "to" in "prohibited by it to the States" used as a preposition referring to the object here? If yes, why? Why is it incorrect to say "I prohibit it to the organization or it was prohibited by me to the organization"

Comment: Members of the US Supreme Court wrestle with this 18th century legal language constantly even today).  You need to quote the sentence in full.  But there is a twist in this.  It involves what JL Austin in the 1950s called a ' performative utterance'.  It means whatever the US Supreme Court says it means.  It is fairly clear that the authors are using the verbs 'delegated' and 'prohibited' as antonyms and so also choosing to use the preposition in the same way twice to balance the period.  Whether it is correct 18th C grammar is out of my depth.

Comment: Idiomatic [V] + [Prep] combinations are covered at (linking to the relevant example) [lingohelp.me preposition after verb reserve: for / to / in / at / by](https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-verb/reserve-for-to-in-at-by/). 'Reserved to' is fairly rare and here always in a legal / political / old religious register. I'll not post an 'answer' as only currency, not meaning/s, of the colligations is/are given here.

Answer (score 1):

> Is "to" in "prohibited by it to the States" used as a preposition referring to the object here?

Yes.

> If yes, why?

Either "for" or "to" can be used. This is indicative of the use of the dative grammatical case in Old English. The **to** or **for** create an adverbial complement.

> Why is it incorrect to say "I prohibit it to the organization or it was prohibited by me to the organization"

It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is like "Cry me a River" an 'ethical dative" or "Dative of reference"
Roughly contemporaneous is Fielding's Tom Jones in which appears "otherwise I would scorn to give it 'em; and they drank me two bottles"